# How to have full CI/CD in openshift?

Tags: continuous-integration, openshift, continuous-delivery

I know it's possible to have that when using Jenkins inside of Openshift, but when using pure build images it seems full CI/CD seems to be missing.

Our perfect scenario for each push to 'master' branch would be:

- **build app**
- run unit tests
- notify team if failed to build
- **deploy image**
- notify if failed to start

Simple Openshift build setup only includes **bold** items.

Can we have full CI/CD inside of Openshift? Or should we do checks outside?
Also notifications on failures are still missing in Openshift as far as I know.

Comment: The intended method of performing these tasks is to use Jenkins (https://docs.okd.io/latest/using_images/other_images/jenkins.html), which is automatically available to the cluster, and you can add things like OpenShift Pipelines with Jenkins to show these things as part of the Web Console (https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/dev_tutorials/openshift_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you had better use the [OpenShift Pipeline Jebkins Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/openshift-pipeline/) for your use.
It can be implemented your own `CI/CD` using various ways, so it's a just sample. Maybe you would undergo trial and error for finding your own `CI/CD` configurations.

For example, simple build and deploy description using `OpenShift Pipeline Jenkins Plugin`. 
For more details, refer [here](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin)
And post notification for the job result is configured using [Cleaning up and notifications](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    name: your-pipeline
  name: your-pipeline
spec:
  runPolicy: Serial
  strategy:
    jenkinsPipelineStrategy:
      jenkinsfile: |-
        node(''){
          stage('some unit tests') {
            sh 'git clone https://github.com/yourproject/yourrepo'
            sh 'python -m unittest tests/unittest_start_and_result_mailing.py'
          }
          stage('Build using your-yourconfig'){
              openshiftBuild(namespace: 'your-project', bldCfg: 'your-buildconfig', showBuildLogs: 'true')
          }
          stage('Deployment using your-deploymentconfig'){
              openshiftDeploy(namespace: 'your-project', depCfg: 'your-deploymentconfig')
          }
          stage('Verify Deployment status'){
              openshiftVerifyDeployment(namespace: 'your-project', depCfg: 'your-deploymentconfig', verifyReplicaCount: 'true')
          }
        }
        post {
          always {
            echo 'One way or another, I have finished'
            deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
          }
          success {
            echo 'I succeeeded!'
          }
          unstable {
            echo 'I am unstable :/'
          }
          failure {
            echo 'I failed :('
          }
          changed {
            echo 'Things were different before...'
          }
        }
    type: JenkinsPipeline
  triggers:
  - github:
      secret: gitsecret
    type: GitHub
  - generic:
      secret: genericsecret
    type: Generic
```

I hope it help you.